# Dont understand this example of a closure in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, closures

I am a little confused regarding closures in this example

```js
function f(param){
  var n=function(){ //n is assigned the function that returns param 
    return param; 
  };
  param++; //increments 1 and n keeps a reference to the param 
  return n; 
}
var inner=f(1);
inner();
```

I understand the concept of closures, I just dont understand how it works in this example.

Comment: Which part don't you understand? Have your tried to read the script and think of how the order and returns might explain how this works? `inner()` is defined as `f()` which is a function call so the result/return of `inner` will match the function result. within `f()` it have another function defined as `n` which returns the `param` back to `f()` but is then incremented

Comment: @NewToJS I dont understand how param++ gets access to the param in the n function

Comment: you can have a look at here for your answer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting

Comment: Sorry, `param` is incremented but then `n` is called which returns the updated `param` since it is called after.

Comment: try to put `console.log` to almost every line of code to see the flow of execution. It helps me to understand `closure` in that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets see in steps whats happening here:

you call function f with argument 1 and assign the result to variable inner.

When f(1) is called, the scope of f has 2 variables (param and n)

The variable params is the passed argument and n is a function.

So, inside function f - 
variable n is initialized to a function, then param is incremented, then n is returned from the function f.

This returned function (n) is assigned to inner.

when inner is called, it returns param - which is in scope of function n due to closure.

Hope the steps were clear.

Now, you're doubt was how n got access to param++. It didn't, param++ was already executed when f(1) was called. All n has is just a reference to the value of param.

Comment: So your saying that their is one copy of param? and they both have a reference to param?

Comment: @akotch, thats right. the anonymous function assigned to n has reference to all variables which are in its own scope + in the scope of its parent function (f in this case)

Answer (score 1):

In `param` becomes a local variable to the function which is not same as the argument of the function `f`. The function `f` is returning `n` which is a function

```js
function f(param) {
  var n = function() { //n is assigned the function that returns param 
    return param;
  };
  param++; // here param become a local variable of the function f
  return n;
}
var inner = f(1);
console.log(inner());
```

Answer (score 1):

Here in this example, the local variable param ends up within a closure of that anonymous function. Here in this case, until the outer function returns, it can change the local execution context which will be used by the anonymous function whenever it gets executed.